# how to get whole csv file and print (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, csv, import

This time i am to get header don't know how can i get whole csv file data and print it
here is my function please help to go forward

```
public function import(Request $request){
        $upload =$request->file('upload-file');
        $filepath= $upload->getRealPath();

        $file=fopen($filepath, 'r');

        $header=fgetcsv($file);
        dd($header);
        die;
    }
```

I want that header should not come here other than header whole data should be print
its foreach loop

```
foreach($users as $user) {
}
```

Here is header which i am getting

```
 array:13 [▼
  0 => "Account Name"
  1 => "Group"
  2 => "Host"
  3 => "Username"
  4 => "Password"
  5 => "Port"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgetcsv` returns the line it's looking at and moves the "pointer" to the next line. If you want to load the entire CSV file into an array you need to loop through the file:

```
<?php
$data = [];
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $i = 0; // Define a counter that tells us which row we're looking at
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // Only capture rows that are greater than 0, i.e. we skip the first row (Headers)
        if ($i > 0) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

var_dump($data);
```

Creating a user for each of the rows of data should be easy:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    User::create($item);
}
```

Regarding validating that the uploaded file is a CSV file you can use [Laravel's validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation), specifically those regarding mimes. For example:

```
'file' => 'file|mimes:csv'
```

If you want to do some validation in your function you can use some of the methods on the `UploadedFile` instance that you get from `$request->file('...');`, specifically you could use `$upload->getClientOriginalExtension()` to get the file extension of the file that was uploaded, or you could use `$upload->getClientMimeType()` to get the mime type of the file, which in the case of a CSV should be `text/csv`:

```
if ($upload->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'csv') {
    // Handle your validation error, probably throw an exception
}

if ($upload->getClientMimeType() != 'text/csv') {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: thanks i get data now how can i skip header mean header should not come in data

Comment: Assuming the header is the first row, you can simply omit the first row when you capture the data, I'll update my answer

Comment: its done one more help please i want to save that data in my db how can i do ... as in create form i was storing my data as  `$user = Users::create($data);` here how can i create it my db.. Please once more update your Question then it will final

Comment: and also a check that file should always be .csv

Comment: Thanks for this favor

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you want to create a user for each row of the data?

Comment: yes you right final thing left that use a check that the choosen file is .csv ?? if its not csv it should not go in that method

Comment: That depends how strict you want to be. Generally you should be able to achieve what you want using Laravel's validation. See my updated answer. Please accept my answer if I've solved your problem :)

Comment: please i want to use in function as you explain for validation please update your answer with that validation

Comment: can you ? mean should i wait for this ? @jonathon

Comment: `$test= $upload->getClientOriginalExtension();
            dd($test);
            die; ` i am getting here extension as "csv" how use it further pls